# Array == double equal,

Tags: php, arrays, operation

I got an array implode variable, $varString, that is setup to return 3 separate values listed below depending on the condition.

- 1
- 2
- 1,2

---

```
If ($varString == 1) 
{
    echo 'APPLE';}
ElseIf ($varString == 2) 
{
echo 'BANANA';}
ElseIf ($varString == 1,2)  //throws an error. 
{
echo 'APPLE and BANANA';}
```

How do I do this for the case of 1,2?

I tried

```
ElseIf ($varString == '1,2')  //throws an error. 
{
echo 'APPLE and BANANA';}

ElseIf ($varString == "1,2")  //throws an error. 
{
echo 'APPLE and BANANA';}
```

Comment: `$varString == "1,2"`

Comment: When i get 1,2 it returns APPLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 1,2 could only be understood by PHP as a string, you should change your script to this:

```
If ($varString == '1') 
    {
        echo 'APPLE';
    }
    ElseIf ($varString == '2') 
    {
        echo 'BANANA';
    }
    ElseIf ($varString == '1,2')  //no it doesn't 
    {
        echo 'APPLE and BANANA';
    }
```

and also, string should always be in `''`

Comment: Usually single quotes should be used.  Not always, though.

Comment: @kevin628 I sometimes use double quotes (especially when I'm writing SQL inside PHP). Are there any rules for when should what be used? For what I can remember it was something like that you could include $variables inside ''s but if they were in ""s it would take literally the $variable text, not its value.

Comment: I go by the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.  Occasionally, for some larger applications, I've needed special escape sequences, and the best way to do it was with double quotes.  And a few templating frameworks use variable expansion, which requires double quotes.

Beyond cases where one can sanely prove the need for double quotes, then one should stick with single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ElseIf ($varString == '1,2') { echo 'APPLE and BANANA';}
```